# ASP.NET 5 beta8 IIS publish static content doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, static

I have very simple ASP.NET 5 app , just one page with static content and js.
after upgrading to beta 8, somehow  I managed to run my app ,except that all static files requests return 302 (redirect) status.

Page itself is rendered without any problem , only static files don't return form IIS.

I installed HttpPlatformHandler v1.2 also I have app.UseStaticFiles(); in my startup.cs configured everything properly. Before upgrade everything was working OK , and also in IIS Express my app runs smoothly.
I tried to google , read all discussions in GitHub.But there seems no solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer seems to migrate to rc1 version. beta 8 is too buggy